# JavaScript creating derived classes without calling superclass constructor

Tags: javascript

So I define classes by using their constructor functions, and in these functions I define all their properties, and do constructor-y things like setting up listeners and such. After defining the constructor, I then go and add all of it's functions directly to its prototype.

To do inheritance, I essentially do this:

```
namespace.Class = function(param) {
    namespace.BaseClass.call(this, param);

    //Other constructor stuff
}

namespace.Class.prototype = new namespace.BaseClass();
namespace.Class.constructor = namespace.Class;
```

The problem is that the BaseClass' constructor gets called when creating the prototype, which causes the prototype to be an instance of that type. This may not be a problem, but it just feels "messy" and performance lagging, and potentially buggy because I have to check if the params are defined.

So my question is: **Is it possible to extend a base class without calling its constructor?** Or will I have to use tricks such as checking if `param` is undefined, or using a loop to do stuff?

Sorry if I've missed the whole point of prototypal inheritance, I am being taught Java in uni, and Java doesn't approve of this type of stuff.

Comment: You may wish to take a look at this library: https://github.com/javascript/augment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The preferred way is to use [`Object.create` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
namespace.Class.prototype = Object.create(namespace.BaseClass.prototype);
```

This creates a new, empty object which inherits from `BaseClass.prototype`, which is all you need at this point.

This is a much cleaner solution than creating an instance of the parent class, because, as you already mentioned, if the super class expects arguments, you don't know which ones to pass.

Comment: This is the second time I've been trying for ages to figure out how to do something, and it turns out there is a method on `Object` to do it...